# Mining patterns in continuous sequence

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, traminer, sequence-analysis

I have data in form of $N$ sequences $s_j=(t_i, e_i)_{i\in\{1,\ldots,n_j\}}$ with $n_j$ data-points each, where $t_i$ is a time-stamp and $e_i$ is a categorial event, say $e_i\in\{A,B,C,D\}$. The $N$ sequences are independent.

I want to find short (i.e., $<<n_j$) patterns of events (say, "DAAB", i.e., I'm not interested in their relative timing) that occur multiple times both within and across the individual time-series. I am not an expert in sequential pattern mining but as far as I understand, those algorithms (GSP, SPADE,...?) require as input a list of subsequent event-lists rather than a continuous stream. I could, of course, try to split each sequence $s_j$ into shorter bits (based on temporal distance in terms of the time of occurence $t_i$) and use those algorithms (any hints on how to do that effectively are most welcome!). But I was wondering if anyone could point me to a method that can handle continuous streams?

I am also interested in methods that are robust against (or estimate directly) "mutations" and "deletions", i.e., that the algorithm could somehow pick up that "DAB", "DABB" and "DAAB" are alike, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not intended for streaming data, it may worth to have a look at the `TraMineR` R package.

With TraMineR you can, among others, find the most frequent subsequences using different counting methods (presence/absence in the sequence, multiple occurrences in each sequences, ...) and time constraints, find the frequent subsequences of length at most k  and/or at least h (see help(seqefsub)).

I illustrate below how to search for subsequences with at most 3 elements using the time-stamped `actcal.tse` data that ships with `TraMineR` (type help(actcal.tse) for details about the data):

```
library(TraMineR)
data(actcal.tse)
actcal.seqe <- seqecreate(id = actcal.tse$id, timestamp = actcal.tse$time, 
      event = actcal.tse$event)

fsub <- seqefsub(actcal.seqe, maxK = 3, pMinSupport = .01)
fsub
```

If you want only subsequences with at least 2 elements, you need the `seqentrans`function of the `TraMineRextras` package:

```
library(TraMineRextras)
fsub <- seqentrans(fsub)
fsub[fsub$data$nevent > 1]
```

Regarding your second point, you could use the `seqdss` function of `TraMineR` to extract the sequences of distinct successive states (DSS), where each spell such as `AAAA` in the sequence is replaced by a single `A`. for example, your three examples `DAB`, `DAAB` and `DABB` all have the same DSS. You could then compute distances between sequences of DSS.

Comment: that looks very interesting, thanks for the link. I will check it out and comment more fully once I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for repeats in your sequence you can try [suffix trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). However, suffix arrays are more efficient but harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! However, I don't seem to understand how I can I use this tree to solve my problem. Can you elaborate a bit more?